# How to hide controls in several panels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to hide all the labels in my panels (not the whole panel). 
For the cases in which labels were just label1, label2.. I would do this (although if you know a simpler way please tell me):

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
   Panel p = this.Controls["panel"+i] as Panel;

   for(int j=0; j<9; i++){
      if(p.Controls["label"+j]!=null) p.Controls["label"+j].Visible=false;
   }
}
```

So in the case where my labels are lbObj, LbInt4.. how do I loop through all of them and hide them? I've tried:

```
foreach(Panel p in Controls) 
    foreach(Label l in p) l.Visible=false;
```

but that does not seem to work.

Comment: So what are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Do you want to hide **all** Labels in the Panel?..or just all Labels with specific name patterns?

Comment: @Idle_Mind both cases would be good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st way:using 2 foreach loop

```
foreach (Panel panel in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
   foreach (var label in panel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
   {
        label.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

2nd way:using LINQ

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Panel>().SelectMany(panel =>panel.Controls.OfType<Label>()))
{
    label.Visible = false;
}
```

your problem is that you are looking inside a panel but you should look for controls inside that panel and

```
Controls.OfType<Panel>()
```

is what you need.

Edit: looking for specific label

```
foreach (Panel panel in Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
     foreach (var label in panel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
     {
         if (label.Text.Contains("label")) // or any other condition that you want to perform
         {
             label.Visible = false;
         }
     }
}
```

same thing with LINQ (a little complex and not so readable):

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Panel>().SelectMany(panel => panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(label => label.Text.Contains("label"))))
{
    label.Visible = false;
}
```

for using LINQ methods you need to add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

namespace.

Comment: OfType doesn't seem to be recognized: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection does not contain a definition for 'OfType'...

Comment: @Vantalk add using System.Linq; namespace. edited the answer, there should be no problem now.

Comment: Added using.System.Linq and it works. This means both examples use Linq I believe. Marked as answer for being most complete.

Comment: @Vantalk OfType<Panel> is a LINQ method in 1st way. and SelectMany() & OfType<Panel>() & Where() in 2nd way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> foreach (Panel p in this.Controls)
>
> > foreach(Label l in p.Controls) l.Visible=false;

Comment: This returns Unable to cast object of type Label to type Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `OfType<T>` filter on your controls collection to just get the type you want, then act accordingly:

```
foreach (Panel p in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>()) {
  foreach (Label l in p.Controls.OfType<Label>()) {
    l.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

This code assumes you do not have more panels inside of other panels, etc.